# Converting a loop to pure functions

Tags: f#

I have this code written for a [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problem in c++:

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i =0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    //Check if multiple of 3 but not multiple of 5 to prevent duplicate
    sum += i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0 ? i: 0;
    //check for all multiple of 5, including those of 3
    sum += i % 5 == 0 ? i: 0;
}
    cout << sum;
```

I'm trying to learn `f#` and rewriting this in `f#`. This is what I have so far:

```
open System

//function to calculate the multiples
let multiple3v5 num =
    num

//function to calculate sum of list items
let rec SumList xs =
    match xs with
    | []    -> 0
    | y::ys -> y + SumList ys

let sum = Array.map multiple3v5 [|1 .. 1000|]
```

What I have may be complete nonsense...so help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sumList` function is a good start. It already iterates (recursively) over the entire list, so you don't need to wrap it in an additional `Array.map`. You just need to extend your `sumList` so that it adds the number only when it matches the specified condition.

Here is a solution to a simplified problem - add all numbers that are divisible by 3:

```
open System

let rec sumList xs =
  match xs with
  | []    -> 0 // If the list is empty, the sum is zero
  | y::ys when y % 3 = 0 -> 
     // If the list starts with y that is divisible by 3, then we add 'y' to the
     // sum that we get by recursively processing the rest of the list
     y + sumList ys
  | y::ys -> 
     // This will only execute when y is not divisible by 3, so we just
     // recursively process the rest of the list and return 
     /// that (without adding current value)
     sumList ys

// For testing, let's sum all numbers divisble by 3 between 1 and 10.
let sum = sumList [ 1 .. 10 ]
```

This is the basic way of writing the function using explicit recursion. In practice, the solution by *jpalmer* is how I'd solve it too, but it is useful to write a few recursive functions yourself if you're learning F#.

The *accumulator parameter* mentioned by *sashang* is a more advanced way to write this. You'll need to do that if you want to run the function on large inputs (which is likely the case in Euler problem). When using accumulator parameter, the function can be written using *tail recursion*, so it avoids stack overflow even when processing long lists.

The idea of a accumulator-based version is that the function takes additional parameter, which represents the sum calculated so far.

```
let rec sumList xs sumSoFar = ...
```

When you call it initially, you write `sumList [ ... ] 0`. The recursive calls will not call `y + sumList xs`, but will instead add `y` to the accumulator and then make the recursive call `sumList xs (y + sumSoFar)`. This way, the F# compiler can do tail-call optimization and it will translate code to a loop (similar to the C++ version).

Comment: :( Man, I think I just need a course on functional languages all together. Thanks for explaining other answers too, this helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if translating from an imperative language solution is a good approach to developing a functional mindset as instrument (C++ in your case) had already defined an (imperative) approach to solution, so it's better sticking to original problem outlay.

Overall tasks from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) are excellent for mastering many F# facilities. For example, you may use list comprehensions like in the snippet below

```
// multipleOf3Or5 function definition is left for your exercise
let sumOfMultiples n =
    [ for x in 1 .. n do if multipleOf3Or5 x then yield x] |> List.sum
sumOfMultiples 999
```

or you can a bit generalize the solution suggested by @jpalmer by exploiting laziness:

```
Seq.initInfinite id
|> Seq.filter multipleOf3Or5
|> Seq.takeWhile ((>) 1000)
|> Seq.sum
```

or you may even use this opportunity to master active patterns:

```
let (|DivisibleBy|_) divisior num = if num % divisor = 0 the Some(num) else None
{1..999}
|> Seq.map (fun i ->
    match i with | DivisibleBy 3 i -> i | DivisibleBy 5 i -> i | _ -> 0)
|> Seq.sum
```

All three variations above implement a common pattern of making a sequence of members with sought property and then folding it by calculating sum.

Comment: I was thinking about just trying to write in f# since its a whole change of mindset.

Comment: Right after posting just another variation came to my mind which is even more direct implementation of original task: `[3..3..999] @ [5..5..999] |> set |> Set.fold (+) 0`

Answer (score 1):

F# has many more functions than just map - this problem suggests using filter and sum, my approach would be something like

```
let valid n = Left as an exercise

let r =
    [1..1000]
    |> List.filter valid
    |> List.sum
printfn "%i" r
```

I didn't want to do the whole problem, but filling in the missing function shouldn't be too hard

Answer (score 0):

This is how you turn a loop with a counter into a recursive function. You do this by passing an accumulator parameter to the loop function that holds the current loop count.

For example:

```
let rec loop acc =
    if acc = 10 then
      printfn "endloop"
    else
      printfn "%d" acc
      loop (acc + 1)

loop 0
```

This will stop when `acc` is 10.